# What is an auto-implemented field

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I have a vb `Class` with the following `Property` in it:

`Public Property Buses As Integer`

Is this equivalent to a more detailed property?

Does the compiler actually transform,  in the background, this line of code into a more detailed `Property` structure which includes a field `_Buses`?

Therefore without actually declaring `_Buses` aslong as I use the structure `Public Property x AS y` then one of these fields will be available?

---

**EDIT**
Actually not too sure if much more can be added than [HERE ON MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answers

**Q:** Does the compiler actually transform, in the background, this line of code into a more detailed Property structure which includes a field `_Buses`?
**A:** Yes

**Q:** Without actually declaring `_Buses` aslong as I use the structure Public Property x AS y then one of these fields will be available?
**A:** Yes

---

#### Explanation (Long Answer)

Auto-implemented properties are generally properties where you do not explicitly specify code for the `Get` and `Set` parts of the property. The general definition of an auto-implemented property is as follows:

```
Public Property Age As Integer
```

or

```
Public Property Age As Integer = 5
```

In both cases, the compiler generates all the backing fields and initializers for you automatically.

Consider the following class with two auto-implemented properties (`Name` and `Age`) and one regular property (`Address`).

```
Public Class Person

    Dim _address As String

    Public Sub New()
        _address = "4, Hutchinson Road"
    End Sub    

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer = 3
    Public Property Address As String
        Get
            Return _address
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _Name & " Age: " & Me.Age.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

The compiler automatically generates backing fields as well as `Get` and `Set` methods for the `Name` and `Age` properties.
The fields generated have the same name as the property with a preceding underscore. Therefore the `Name` property's backing field is `_Name` and the `Age` property's backing field is `_Age`.

The auto-generated fields also have the `DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)` and `CompilerGenerated` attributes attached to them.

The `DebuggerBrowsable` attributes prevents the field from being displayed in the Auto-Complete list in the code editor. This, however, does not prevent you from accessing the field directly in your code, as you can see in the `ToString` method where I use the `_Name` field directly.
The `CompilerGenerated` attribute indicates that the field was created by the compiler.

The `Age` property (as well as all auto-implemented properties with initializers) is initialized in the class's default constructor.

The decompiled version of the class above looks like this:

```
Public Class Person
    ' Methods
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Age = 3
        Me._address = "4, Hutchinson Road"
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Join(" ", New String() { Me._Name, Me.Age.ToString })
    End Function


    ' Properties
    Public Property Address As String
        Get
            Return Me._address
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._address = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Age As Integer
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Get
            Return Me._Age
        End Get
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Set(ByVal AutoPropertyValue As Integer)
            Me._Age = AutoPropertyValue
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Get
            Return Me._Name
        End Get
        <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
        Set(ByVal AutoPropertyValue As String)
            Me._Name = AutoPropertyValue
        End Set
    End Property


    ' Fields
    Private _address As String
    <CompilerGenerated, DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)> _
    Private _Age As Integer
    <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated> _
    Private _Name As String
End Class
```

As you can see, the fields `_Name` and `_Age` are generated for you automatically so you can use them in your code without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer: yes, internally this is transformed to a full property section. You can even access `_Buses` in your code.

But you should optimally set a default as well (not mandatory though):

```
Public Property Buses As Integer = 0
```

The drawback using this short syntax is that you cannot perform validation on the values during its `Set()` (you can of course do this when you need to use the value, but that kind of or in part defeats the purpose of using properties). If you are building a user-control you would probably do things such as `Invalidate` and so forth on the `Set()`, so although easier on the eye (and fingers), it is very often better to use the full section IMHO.