# Why does a underscored variable that is not declared not give an debug error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

This code does not give a compile error in VS 2017 (15.9.5)?

Why could that be?

```
Class BugInclass
    Public Property myProp As String
    Public Sub MyFct()
        myProp = _myProp
    End Sub
End Class
```

note that the "_myProp" is not decalred - it is just treated as if it was "myProp".

Comment: I'm not sure why, but i've noticed it's only true when `myProp` is declared as a property. `_myProp` in this case is a field. When you declare `myProp` using the Dim statement then it is a field and you will get an error saying `_myProp is not declared`. So i'm pretty sure it's by design, i am also interested to know why though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an auto-implemented field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909444/what-is-an-auto-implemented-field)

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks i think the answer might be the same but the question/problem is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an auto-property and they are just syntactic sugar.  You write this code:

```
Public Property myProp As String
```

but what actually gets compiled is this:

```
Private _myProp As String

Public Property myProp As String
    Get
        Return _myProp
    End Get
    Set
        _myProp = value
    End Set
End Property
```

That second snippet is what we used to have to write for all properties up until a few years ago.  The auto-property is far more convenient but the old, verbose code is still there behind the scenes so the implicit backing field still exists.

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton - you can still get the second snippet by typing Property and two tabs.The prototype produced is a fill in the highlighted items and press tab to move between them.